# Is it possible to have a pop-up upon using the [game-rec] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, game-recommendations, tag-warning-request

There have been many [game-rec] questions being asked recently, despite them being defined as out of our scope. I don't know what the Stack Exchange engine is capable of, but would it somehow be possible for a little dialogue to pop up stating something along the lines of...

> warning: game-rec questions are likely to be closed

...perhaps with a link to the relevant meta discussion? I don't know how effective this would be, but I think it would reduce some of the [game-rec]s still being asked.

(Just brainstorming, as I find it curious how people are still asking game-rec questions.)

Comment: To address your parens, it's pretty easy to make the logical jump from 'Place to ask about games' to 'Place to ask about what games to play'. The greater majority of incoming game recs don't come pre-loaded with the tag; they get tagged by cleanup crews who use it to mark the question for others to find. I'm not even sure wholesale deletion of all of the questions would stop it. It'll make it less likely for people to come here, but they still will come.

Comment: Ahh, didn't realize that they were generally added in after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can blacklist the tag and delete it. That's about it.

Answer (score 2):

As Grace Note said, most game recommendation questions aren't tagged [game-rec] initially, so there wouldn't be much point in showing a warning when it's used. Usually by the time people are aware of the [game-rec](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-rec) tag, they are also aware that they shouldn't use it. :)