# Why do we have a game-rec tag if it's off topic?

Tags: discussion, tags, game-recommendations

Looking at the [list of questions for the game-rec tag](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-rec) and [this meta question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1627/is-it-possible-to-have-a-pop-up-upon-using-the-game-rec-tag), why does this tag even exist if it's off topic?

Comment: See also: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2072/why-are-there-so-many-game-recommendation-questions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was originally created because the question class was *not* originally off-topic. It was a contentious subject, and so we used the tag to help classify them en-masse. Generally, this kind of "tagging the kind of question" isn't all that useful on the site, but the usage of [*-rec] for this is actually a Stack Exchange practice that dates back to Super User.

I've stated [back when I started deleting those questions](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2072/why-are-there-so-many-game-recommendation-questions/2077#2077) that we should phase out that tag after we finally started to erase our library of them.

> The game-rec tag is also probably going to be phased out. Remember that one of the reasons we use "*-rec" as a syntax is that [it is obscure and less likely to be used](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/517/why-was-game-recommendations-shortened-to-game-rec/519#519). Now that we don't want the question type to come at all, the tag is meaningless as it categorizes an off-topic subject matter. We don't tag shopping-recommendations, and those are equally off-topic.
>
> As such, please do not tag future game-rec questions as "game-rec". Please just vote to close them and direct them to the policy in our updated FAQ. The "good" questions that still have the tag will probably be swapped for some different tag.

The tag currently still persists because the tag has not been completely removed yet, so it's not unusual to imagine that some of the policing users familiar with the policy on the enforcement level did not get the memo about not adding the tag.

Comment: Those were difficult times...

Comment: Oops. I think I... missed that memo :)

Comment: I add the tag so that, if we ever decide to modify our stance, we can look at that tag within the deleted questions... is that a problem?

Comment: @badp I think it's ultimately a monstrous endeavour to think about, thanks to all of the inconsistency in the tag. Also, *until* such a reversal ever occurs, all it does is persist a live tag that no one can use. If you still want to, feel free to tag them *after they're deleted* - this lets you add the tag, prevents the tag from persisting on the live end, and also prevents you from bumping the question to add that tag. I remain opposed to tagging them while they're still alive.

Comment: Oops. I think I... also missed that memo.

Comment: If we all go insane and decide to allow them, I don't think we'll need to dig up the deleted ones.

Comment: @Grace That works too, duly noted.

Comment: Bringing back all the old game-rec questions would be this site's equivalent of a zombie apocalypse.

Comment: @bwarner Don't worry, I've got my shotgun at the ready.

Comment: @bwarner man, that's a great thing to do on April 1st, undelete them all for just one day :)

Comment: @Oak or a little JavaScript that changes all the question titles to some variation of "Can you recommend a good -genre- game for the -system-?"

Comment: Wait, what?  I thought there weren't any 'good' `[game-rec]` questions.  I suggested keeping existing the ones with useful content [in the comments to one of your previous posts](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2072/why-are-there-so-many-game-recommendation-questions/2077#2077), but you rejected that.

Comment: @NickT If you're referring to my quoted passage, that was referring to questions that had the [game-rec] tag that were not actually game-rec questions. There was only a single instance, really, though I can't even remember what it was other than not really being a stellar question. I stand by exactly by the statement I made earlier.