# The "off-topic" tag roundup, 2012/01/20

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burnination

Following up on my post from yesterday:

[On the coming murder of "dependent" and "meta" tagging](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3811/on-the-coming-murder-of-meta-tagging)

Here is a sampling of "off-topic" tags from the top 20% or so (a totally unscientific 20%, to be sure - I just stopped after I got a whole bunch) of all tags on the site.

**Why are these tags under consideration?  Why is the answer burnination rather than X or Y?**

The template for suggesting these tags for permanent burnination is the [game-rec](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-rec) tag.  It's been discussed a couple of times, so I don't want to rehash it here;  please review:

[Why do we have a game-rec tag if it's off topic?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2319/why-do-we-have-a-game-rec-tag-if-its-off-topic)

[Why are there so many game recommendation questions?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2072/why-are-there-so-many-game-recommendation-questions/2077#2077)

[sales](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sales) - Many off-topic questions about sales figures for games.  Also a few "shopping advice and recommendations" questions.

[game-rec](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-rec) - See the linked meta posts above.  If there's value in keeping some of the questions around, the suggestion is re-tagging them.

[legal](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal) - Many closed questions under this tag, (mostly regarding "does X count as piracy?") and quite a few that would stand alone without it - Gaming.SE is a gaming site, and not a legal site.  We are not lawyers, and should not attempt to provide legal advice.

[release-date](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/release-date) - Speculation of the future of the industry and of upcoming releases + Too Localized - either we're giving information about a game that hasn't been released yet (and release dates are often subject to change) or the data is irrelevant once the game's been released.

[theory](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theory) - Ambiguous tag (I've marked it before) - what is a "theory" question?  In one definition, it asks us to speculate, so I dumped it here.

[game-development](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-development) - Off topic, likely to be migrated.

Answer (score 3):

- Deleted all off-topic questions from [game-rec](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-rec). The remainder questions should remain tagged as they are, for lack of other tags.
- [sales](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sales) was small, so I burninated it by hand
- Again, I disagree with touching [legal](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal) until further discussion on meta. We have plenty open questions here.
- Deleted closed [release-date](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/release-date) questions *asking about single games*. Tag renamed to [releases](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/releases) to discourage more questions about release *dates.*
- Handled all questions that just had [theory](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theory); the rest have been pwnd by Rebecca.
- Deleted all closed [game-development](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-development) questions, retagged the rest.

Comment: re: game-rec, Grace says: "The tag currently still persists because the tag has not been completely removed yet" and suggests renaming it to something else post-purge.  Do we need to discuss further what it should be called in its next life?

Comment: [tag:theory] ==> http://i.stack.imgur.com/pi1t3.jpg

Comment: @RebeccaChernoff There you fixed it.